# How to use nbdime with Github, desktop?

Tags: github, diff, github-desktop

I want to use git on jupyter notebook, but I cannot introduce nbdime to github desktop.

I have installed the nbdime on my system and it works fine, but I cannot connect it to github desktop. `nbdime config-git --enable --global`
is the comment to have it work with Git, but how to make it work with Github desktop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.